# Xamarin Monotouch UISplitViewController: How can I set or create the delegate for UISplitViewController?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a UISplitViewController and am trying to get an event from my MasterViewController and change the DetailViewController completely. So as I figured out, this can be done basically by doing the following:

```
ViewControllers[1] = new MyNewViewController();
```

When I do this, nothing changes though! I know it has something to do with setting the Delegate but I don't know where and how I need to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override UISplitViewControllerDelegate to do whatever needs to be done. Example from one of my apps:

```
using System;

using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace PythonMath
{
    class SplitViewControllerDelegate : UISplitViewControllerDelegate
    {
        public override bool ShouldHideViewController(
            UISplitViewController svc,
            UIViewController viewController,
            UIInterfaceOrientation inOrientation)
        {
            return (! InAppPurchaseModel.Editor.Purchased) ||
                inOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait ||
                inOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;
        }
    }
}
```

Then assign it to UISplitViewController's delegate:

```
var SplitViewController = new UISplitViewController();
SplitViewController.Delegate = new SplitViewControllerDelegate ();
```